# Will multiplying by rand() in MySQL affect performance?

Tags: mysql, performance, random, probability

```
SELECT *, (nlike  / (nlike + ndlike)) * rand() AS rnk FROM tbl
order by rnk desc;
```

I know that ORDER BY RAND() is pretty detrimental to performance; however, I'm primarily concerned with multiplying by rand(). Will this cause the system to slow down? Any alternatives to this?

Comment: It's obvious that `ORDER BY rnk` is slower than `ORDER BY RAND()`

Comment: what do you want to achieve?order by random?

Comment: It's basically an algorithm to give chances to people who have posts that have no chance of being seen.

Comment: @inivisal How is it slower?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to cheat your way around it won't help. You're adding a new randomly-calculated field to each record, and sorting by that, which will require exactly the same retrieval strategy as ORDER BY RAND().

Comment: So there's no other way? And will multiplying by rand() be harmful to performance?

Comment: The multiply has nothing to do with it--that takes no time at all. What takes time is fetching the records from the database without using any indexes, and when you order by something that's not stored, it can't use any indexes.

Comment: So what would be a good solution?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. I have no idea what your application is, so there's no way I can optimize it.

Comment: It's a simple like and dislike comment app. I'm basically trying to sort each comment by rank.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you need anything random for that. Just store rank in the table and have an index on it.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you are trying to limit the results by some number, rather than just ordering everyone.

In that case, you can limit the results using `rand()` in the `where` clause and then choose a random subset based on the like/dislike formula:

```
select t.*
from t
where rand() < 0.01
order by (nlike  / (nlike + ndlike)) desc
```

Or even:

```
order by (nlike  / (nlike + ndlike))*rand() desc
```

The key to the performance gain here is that you have reduced the size of the data before the sort.  This is a slightly different way of thinking about your problem.  First you are drawing a random sample and then ordering them.